# Dart Angular Components - How to get full path of selected values?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm implementing a **Single Selection Nested Tree** from the [Angular Components Example](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components_example/) and the example code gets the selected value.

I want to get the full path with the selected value as well as the selected parent groups titles.

Is this possible? I've been searching for an API documentation but haven't found one yet.

Example:

```
<material-tree
        [options]="nestedOptions"
        [expandAll]="expandAll"
        [selection]="singleSelection">
</material-tree>
```

-

```
final SelectionOptions nestedOptions = new _NestedSelectionOptions([
 new OptionGroup(
    ['Animated Feature Films', 'Live-Action Films', 'Documentary Films'])
], {
'Animated Feature Films': [
  new OptionGroup([
    'Cinderalla',
    'Alice In Wonderland',
    'Peter Pan',
    'Lady and the Tramp',
  ])
],
'Live-Action Films': [
  new OptionGroup(
      ['Treasure Island', 'The Littlest Outlaw', 'Old Yeller', 'Star Wars'])
],
'Documentary Films': [
  new OptionGroup(['Frank and Ollie', 'Sacred Planet'])
],
'Star Wars': [
  new OptionGroup(['By George Lucas'])
],
'By George Lucas': [
  new OptionGroup(
      ['A New Hope', 'Empire Strikes Back', 'Return of the Jedi'])
]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built in way to display the path information. To make that work you would want to create a class for your values that stores the parent information and makes that accessible. Then use an ItemRenderer to ensure it is displayed as a string when used in the Material Tree.